# If lock can prevent the use of volatile

Tags: c

How could I know a variable is read from memory not register without using volatile.

```
static uint64 counter;

void thread(void *arg){
  while(counter < (uint64)arg){
    acquire(&lock)
    counter++;
    release(&lock);
  }
}
```

I never doubt with that before, but if there's compiler optimization, won't it produce
bad result.
I also find the volatile is rare in xv6 kernel code, and I wonder is there some tricks to
suppress optimization through compiler's command line to prevent use of volatile.

Comment: It depends on your line of work, but I've never had cause to use `volatile` in the last 35+ years.  And I did get rid of the attribute from some code that used it unnecessarily.  If you take the address of a variable, it cannot be stored in a register.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? It looks you are synchronizing threads and you shouldn't use `volatile` for that. Use the proper thread synchronization primitives like mutexes, locks, atomics etc.  If you use the proper synchronization primitives, you can turn on the highest level of optimization and it will still do the right thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `volatile` as long as your locking library is properly implemented - it will (by design) guarantee the correct behavior in spite of compiler optimizations, threads contending on the same resource, scheduling on other processors and cores, etc.

A properly-implemented `acquire` and `release` will guarantee that the compiler won't produce undesired reorderings, and more importantly, it will also guarantee that a *processor* (and its associated cache controller) won't produce undesired reorderings (which can occur on some processor architectures, *even if the compiler emits the desired sequence of operations*).

**One approach** to doing this is with the use of barriers. I present it more as an explanation of how things work, and *not* as a recommendation to handwrite such synchronization code:

- The `acquire` function includes a so-called *memory barrier* with "acquire semantics" - an acquire barrier means that any code following it (i.e. the code inside the critical section) must NOT be reordered to happen BEFORE the barrier. This means that any other threads and processors will necessarily see the acquisition of the lock before any of the writes from the critical section.
- The `release` function provides an analogous memory barrier that prevents anything in the critical section from being reordered AFTER the barrier. This ensures that other threads will see the effects from the critical section BEFORE they see the lock being released.

Unless you are writing a low-level library and are prepared to thoroughly prove, verify, and test it, you should not be writing this kind of barrier code yourself. It's very easy to make subtle mistakes, performance inefficiencies, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unaware of memory barriers before.